How to use `dune test` for a program which reads files from the local directory?
I have a project built in Dune, with the structure
| project_dir
 -| bin
   | dune
   | main.ml

 -| lib
   | dune
   | libfile.ml

 -| test
   | dune
   | test.ml

 | data.csv 

The libfile.ml reads the data in data.csv just fine, with a relative file path parallel to the current working directory (i.e., when main.ml runs, libfile.ml finds data.csv at the root of the project directory).
However, when I call dune test, it cannot find the file.  I tried resolving this by adding the files to the ./test/dune dependencies.  But when doing that, the files have to be referenced relative to the ./test directory!  In order for the tests to find files, I need to give the path ../data.csv.
So basically, one file path works for running and a different file path works for testing.  I know that I could make all function calls take a file path argument and specify different paths in different places, but I am giving a very simplified description of the project, because it is quite large.  Given how complex the project is, it would be much better if I could somehow either control the "current working directory" of the test or main execution, so that I could make one match the other.
Thanks for any help!

Dune doesn't run test at the current directory, but at the build directory of test(e.g. ./_build/default/tests).
That's why you can't access your data.csv file from the current directory during testing, as the way bin/main.ml did.
I believe the simplest way to use the <root-of-project>/data.csv file in test is to add it as a test dependency using dune's Dependency Specification. This way, dune will copy it to the parent of the test's build directory.
Moreover, Dune will track modifications to the data.csv file, ensuring that you're always use latest version of data.csv in your tests and avoiding most of unnecessary copy.
File ./test/dune:
(test
 (name test_so_answer)
 (deps
  ; %{project_root} indicate project root according to https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts/variables.html
  (file %{project_root}/data.csv)))

File ./test/test_entry.ml:
let () =
  let path = "../data.csv" in
  Printf.printf "File %s exists: %b\n" path (Sys.file_exists path)

Run test:
dune test

And you'll get:
File ../data.csv exists: true

